# wlst authentication exception prompt user again

Tags: authentication, exception, wlst

I have written a couple of wlst scripts which work as expected. The script starts by prompting the user for a username/password, connects to the admin server and then performs the tasks (deployment, startup/shutdown etc etc).

The problem I am having is at the first step - if the user enters an incorrect username/password, I want the script to prompt it one more time for this information. Note that I want the user to be prompted a second time  **only** if the username/password is incorrect - not if, say the admin server is down.

I am trying the following piece of code and it is not working as expected (it never enters the first except block). Apparently, my lack of OOPS programming experience is hindering completion of this simple task. Hoping someone can help out with this step.

try:

```
    connect(username, password, 't3://ADMIN_SERVER:ADMIN_PORT')
```

except SecurityException:

```
    print '\nAuthentication error, add logic to retry\n"
    exit(exitcode=1)
```

except:

```
    print "\n\n ALL OTHER ERRORS \n\n "
```

(I have also tried NamingException,AuthenticationException in place of SecurityException but it did not help either)

Answer (score 0):

Simple except block works for me...

You can also try the following way NameError  instead of other trials

1. `try: connect(username, password,
   't3://ADMIN_SERVER:ADMIN_PORT') 
   except NameError, e:

       print "Check username, passwd values : ", sys.exc_info()[0],
   sys.exc_info()[1]`

You can handle error e with your way.